# WSO2 products and Carbon version compatibility

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I want to include multiple WSO2 products in 1 Carbon Management console. I started with Carbon 4.1.0. However, when installing features, not all products are listed (e.g. BRS, Identity Server etc). I understand that these will added in the future (?).

You can add additional repositories in the console, pointing to other versions of Carbon.

Now my questions are:
Will this result in a stable environment (multiple carbon versions) and products that can work together?
Is this the way to go (having 1 management console for multiple products)?
Are 4.x carbon based products compatible with 3.x carbon based products?
Is there an overview of WSO2 product versions and what Carbon version contains the features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It is not recommended to install multiple features without careful analysis of them. Actually products are carefully analysed and proven features that are grouped together to solve common problems. As an example if you combine AS + ESB features yes you can have it but
it may result in poor performance in ESB since your services are hosted in the same server too. (Likewise there are many negatives). Further some of the combinations are not properly tested in an production environment and will have some unidentified issues, But released products are tested properly and used in production too.

2) Not compatible. You cannot install 3.x features in 4.x.

3) You may refer this for product overviews
http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/

Comment: Hi Shelan, thanks for your prompt response. Regarding 1: so if I need a 'full stack', then I need separate products. Is there a way to still have a single management console across these products? Looking at the matrix it is quite a puzzle to choose what Carbon version includes the riches set, since it seems to differ from version to version

Comment: The point is, I am looking at the correct decision weighing up-to-date versions of products and having a central management console for managing the SOA platform. To what extend can separate installed products use each others capability?

Comment: Yes you need to have different servers. But i advice without using all of them carefully analyse what is your need and then decide on the products rather starting from a full blown setup. All the latest products are carbon 4.x based hence they are compatible with each other. Without worrying about the which carbon minor version they are dependent on, go to the product page and download the product which you need. Ex. ESB 4.6.0 and AS 5.1.0 etc. are the latest. We do not release all the product as a whole bunch and different products has their own release cycle

Comment: So you cannot get all the products against one carbon minor version. But all of them are different releases of 4.x family. It is not possible to have a one management console if you have different servers.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer. (I ticked the accept answer). Is there any reason why you should not want 1 management console? Is having a central management console something on the roadmap? I am sure operations people will surely like it. Furthermore, this better underlines what is written on http://wso2.com/products/carbon/ "Easily Extensible and Future-Proof". Currently I think what is said there is not what the product can/supports.

Comment: Since we have front end components and back end components. You can do it in the following way. http://ddweerasiri.blogspot.com/2011/04/monitoring-multiple-wso2-server.html. So you can configure that. On more positive note there are future plans to get the monitoring and deployment more dev ops friendly which will address most of these concerns. Thanks

Comment: Can I safely use Carbon 4.1.X based products together with 4.0.X products? Like for example ESB 4.7.0 with IS 4.1.0. This is not quite clear neither from your previous answers nor looking at the release table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

About your initial question, under carbon 4.1.0 still only AS(5.1.0) is released. Rest will be released later on (sometimes may be with carbon 4.1.x or 4.2.x).